# Web2py Access Control & MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, web2py

I'm using MongoDB for my database.

```
db = DAL('mongodb://localhost:27017/app')
```

When I attempt to register a new user, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/restricted.py", line 209, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/ecosystem/web2py/applications/app/controllers/default.py", line 146, in <module>
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/globals.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/home/ecosystem/web2py/applications/app/controllers/default.py", line 108, in user
    return dict(form=auth())
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/tools.py", line 1205, in __call__
    return getattr(self,args[0])()
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/tools.py", line 2180, in register
    self.add_membership(group_id, form.vars.id)
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/tools.py", line 2963, in add_membership
    record = membership(user_id = user_id,group_id = group_id)
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/dal.py", line 7656, in __call__
    else:
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/dal.py", line 8787, in select
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/dal.py", line 5092, in select
    row=[]
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1058, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/ecosystem/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1002, in _refresh
    self.__uuid_subtype))
OverflowError: MongoDB can only handle up to 8-byte ints
```

If I look in my database tables, everything seems okay except a couple fields.

In auth_user (not sure about this one):

```
registration_id:""
```

In auth_event (I'm assuming this should not be null):

```
user_id:null
```

What is the best way to resolve this? If possible, I'd like to use MongoDB for all database transactions (including access control / authentication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: You can avoid this by upgrading to the latest version of Web2py. This is now fully supported so you do not need to use two different databases.

---

I wasn't able to solve this problem directly, but I was able to create a work-around. In db.py, I define two separate database connections:

```
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'])
db1 = DAL('mongodb://localhost:27017/collection')
```

I call `db` (eventually a mysql database) on all auth functions (registration, login, is logged in checks), while handling everything else (including detailed member profiles) in mongo. I often bypass `db1` DAL entirely by using the pymongo API.